# vue.js bidirectional calculation on input value

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to do bidirectional calculations on an input in vue.js? My data is in inches and has to stay in inches. I want to convert my data to other units in a input box and after the user put in some value it has to be converted back to inches.

```
<input :value="someCrazyBidirectionalCalculation(dataInInches)">
```

Follow up question:

I followed the guide to make a two-way filter in vue.js v2

```
<v-unit-input label="Height" v-model="parameters.height"></v-unit-input>


Vue.component('v-unit-input', {
    template:
    '<v-text-field ref="input" :label="label" type="number" suffix="mm" :value="value" @input="toInch($event.target.value)" @blur="toMm"></v-text-field>',
    props: {
        value: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        label: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.toMm()
    },
    methods: {
        toInch: function (value) {
            this.$emit('input', this.value / 25.4)
        },
        toMm: function () {
            this.$refs.input.value = this.value * 25.4
        },
    }
})
```

It does it job when sending data from the backend to the input but changing the input gives this error:

[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "input": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Edit 2:

It seems $event.target.value was the problem. My value is stored in $event.
Data from the backend is converted from inches to mm and when entering data in mm it is converted back to inches but it is also displayed in inches as soon as I press a number. Is it possible to only show it in mm?

Comment: You can use a @keyup on each field to trigger a method to convert and update the other field when something is typed in in either

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean here. How does the user know what unit they are using?

Comment: There is only one input field. The users unit depends on his settings. But the backend is always in inches.

Comment: I've found the two way filter from vuejs v1 does exactly what I want but it's depricated. I have to follow this guide https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you use a filter but not in de same input maybe you can put the result on inches after than input.

```
<input v-model="number">
<label>{{ number | inches }}</label>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

It's finally working.

```
Vue.component('v-unit-input', {
    template:
    '<v-text-field ref="textfield" :label="label" suffix="mm" :value="to_mm" @input="toInch($event)" v-bind="$attrs" "></v-text-field>',
    props: {
        value: Number,
        label: String,
    },
    computed: {
        to_mm(){
            const mm = Math.round(this.value * 25.4);
            return mm
        },
    },

    methods: {
        toInch: function (val) {
            if (val !== '-') {
                const result = val / 25.4;
                this.$emit('input', result)
            }
        }
    }
})
```